# SCSS variables turning into "undefined variable"

Tags: sass

Here's a basic view of my structure:

```
+- application.scss
+- _variables.scss
+- normalize.scss
```

`application.scss` contains

```
@import "variables";
@import "normalize";
```

`_variables.scss` contains

```
$test-variable: Verdana;
```

Which works if it is used within `application.scss`, but it doesn't carry over to `normalize.scss`. From what I've understood that should be possible. Or? Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: It is strange. I have a similar structure and variables declared previously are available in other files. I think you need to find somewhere a mistake.

Comment: I got it working by simply renaming my normalize.scss file into _normalize.scss, thus making it a 'partial'. It still doesn't seem entirely right though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import your _variables.scss into your normalize stylesheet to access those variables.

Comment: Just like normal CSS imports? There's no other way? The reason is it will be quite a lot of variables as I keep building, and fiddly for testing and prototyping when each file repeats the same import, rather than letting me comment out just one line.

Comment: Basically because you are compiling normalize.scss as a separate style sheet, it is not seeing those variables unless you use @import "variables" at the top of that document. If you compile normalize .scss into your application.scss, you might not have to do that. aka have the file be _normalize.scss instead of normalize.scss.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import the variables partial to any file where the variables are in use.

Answer (score 1):

You DON'T have to import the variables partial to any fine where the variables are in use. (Atleast, not anymore).

Just always use the _variables partial before the other @imports which use _variables.